# Fusionar dos arrays

Tags: php, laravel, array

Hola a todos tengo dos array:

```
    $pedidosper=new PedidosPer();
    $salidapedidos=$pedidosper->salidaPedidos();

    $productosBloqueados= new PedidosPer();
    $productosBloqueados=$productosBloqueados->salidaPedidosBloqueados();

    $newArray = array();
    $newArray2 = array();

    for ($i=0; $i<count($salidapedidos); $i++)
    {
        for($j=0; $j<count($productosBloqueados); $j++)
        {
            if($salidapedidos[$i]->id_order == $productosBloqueados[$j]->idOrder)
            {
                $newArray[] = array('id_order' => $salidapedidos[$i]->id_order,'shop_name' => $salidapedidos[$i]->name_shop,'payment' => $salidapedidos[$i]->payment,'customer_firstname' => $salidapedidos[$i]->customer_firstname,
                'customer_lastname' => $salidapedidos[$i]->customer_lastname,'reference' => $salidapedidos[$i]->reference,'total'=> $salidapedidos[$i]->total,$salidapedidos[$i]->fecha,$productosBloqueados[$j]->estado_id);
            }
        }
            $newArray2[] = array($salidapedidos[$i]->id_order,$salidapedidos[$i]->name_shop,$salidapedidos[$i]->payment,$salidapedidos[$i]->customer_firstname,
            $salidapedidos[$i]->customer_lastname,$salidapedidos[$i]->reference,$salidapedidos[$i]->total,$salidapedidos[$i]->fecha,"");
        
    }
```

Les explico: Yo estoy consultando la base de datos A y una base de datos B, resulta que son bases de datos diferentes pero comparten informacion común. Entonces el primer ciclo for esta comparado y dice: Si el id_order de la BD A es igual a idOrder de la BD B entonces dame los datos de A y crea un arreglo con esos datos mas los datos de B. Ese array ha quedado de maravilla es decir $newArray.

Ahora existe un $newArray2 la idea de esa variable es que en el estén los datos que no estén en $newArray pero mi idea es fucionarlo, es decir, quiero fucionar el $newArray y el $newArray2.

Si ven la foto newArray

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

veran que están los datos con los campos que quiero

pero si ven la foto de newArray2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

verán que están los mismos datos fijense en la clave id_order yo quiero sustituir esos datos ya que los que están newArray son los que quiero finalmente. Espero me haya explicado bien y puedan ayudarme a salir del hueco. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es agregar la información de *newArray* a *newArray2*. Por lo que veo sólo hay un cambio de orden al nombrar un índice (shop_name) y un par de índices (0 y 1).

Puedes hacerlo a través del id_order:

```
$n = count($newArray2);
$m = count($newArray);

for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++){
   $newArray2[$i]->shop_name = $newArray[$i]->name_shop;
   for($j=0;$j<$m;$j++){
       if($newArray2[$i]->reference == $newArray[$j]['reference']){
           $newArray2[$i]->data = array($newArray[$j][0],$newArray2[$j][1]);
       }
   }
}
```

Espero haber respondido a tu pregunta.